# angular payments returns invalid card with test data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to congifure stripe in angular js using the angular-payments app found here

https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments

the problem is that it seems to be returning invalid_card errors even with the test data.

Here is the error:

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens 402 (Payment Required)
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.c(index):3 Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.e(index):3 Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.a(index):3 Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.Stripe.xhr(index):2 Stripe.a._rawRequest(index):2 Stripe.a.request(index):2 Stripe.token.a.create(index):2 Stripe.card.b.createToken(index):2 Stripe.a._channelListener(index):2 Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.H.Socket.t.concat.incoming(index):2
```

I'm setting my publishable key and including Stripe.js without a problem, and I know that the call is completed, as I'm picking up the error in the ResponsHandler

any thoughts what may be causing this?

here is the code:

form

```
<form name="myform" id="signup-form" stripe-handler="saveCustomer">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="card_number">Card Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="myform.number.$card.type"/>
    </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="CVC"> CVC</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="4" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type"/>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="expiry"> Expiry</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" size="2" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" />

  </div>

<div class="text-center">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
    <h3>Thanks For Your Money!</h3>

    <button type="submit"  class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

here is the contoller function:

```
// function to process the form
$scope.saveCustomer = function(status, response) {

        if (response.error) {
            // Show the errors on the form
           console.log(response);
           console.log(response.error);
          } else {
            // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
            var token = response.id;
            console.log(token);
            formData.token = token;   
          }
    }
```

and my index.html header includes...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('my-key-here');
  // ...
</script>
```

The wierd thing is that it was working with stripe-angluar which is another repo for processing stripe - any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might be creating the token incorrectly. I was having the same problem. What worked for me was setting the card like this:

```js
Stripe.card.createToken({
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2016,
    "cvc": '123'
}, function(status, response) {
  stripeResponseHandler(status, response);
});
```

Instead of this  (notice how the card object is created twice - thus the "Stripe.isDoubleLoaded" error, I believe ):

```js
Stripe.card.createToken({
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2016,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
}, function(status, response) {
  stripeResponseHandler
});
```